# Ejecutar y comprender un script mediante un Doker file

Tags: docker, go, docker-machine

E estado trabajando en una pequeña aplicación en Go (Golang) que se muestra en mi navegador mediante un MUX o multiplexor :

```
func main() {
    //estoy usando un multiplexor para mostrar en host
    mux := http.NewServeMux() 
    mux.HandleFunc("/", Inicio)
    log.Println("server corriendo...")
    //esta es la instrucción para ver mi proyecto en localhost:4000
    http.ListenAndServe(":4000", mux)     
}
```

Ahora por cuestiones de permisos con la base de datos me an comentado que suba como una imagen mi codigo a Doker lo cual logre con un doker file, colocando el documento en mi carpeta de proyecto y ejecutando con "doker build ." para crear mi imagen en docker

Mi duda es que no estoy muy seguro como poder ver este proyecto en mi navegador en el puerto localhost:4000 en el que quiero trabajar ya que aun no se como asignar un porto para mi imagen de doker

Comment: Todo será mucho más fácil si incluyes el dockerfile en tu pregunta :) Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

como estas?

El comando docker build . te va a buildear una imagen de docker, para correr la misma tienes que ejecutar el comando run.

Mi recomendación es que crees la imagen con un tag para luego poder utilizarla de la siguiente manera :

```
docker build -t myimage:first_tag .
```

Luego puedes correr el commando run con las flags que tu quieras por ejemplo

```
docker run --expose 80 myimage:first_tag bash
```

Otra opción es que te descarges el cliente desktop de Docker que te va a ayudar mucho de forma gráfica!